# How can I insert data with the correct foreign keys?

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I have a table called `Answers` which has a *foreign key* named "questions_id" referenced to the `Questions` table `id` column.

How can I insert an answer into the `Answers` table with the correct foreign key?

**Questions.php**

```
class Questions extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'questions';

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Answers');
    }
}
```

**Answers.php**

```
class Answers extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'answers';
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function store()
{

    $Question = new Questions;
    $Question->question     = Input::get('question'); 
    $Question->timestamps   = false;
    $Question->save();


    $Answer = new Answers;
    $Answer->answer       = Input::get('answer');
    $Answer->timestamps = false;
    $Answer->save();
*/          // redirect
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created nerd!');
    return Redirect::action('Controller@index');

}
```

**Form.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@index')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ Form::label('question', 'Question') }}
       {{ Form::text('question', Input::old('question'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ Form::label('answer', 'Answer') }}
       {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Create ', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}    
{{ Form::close() }}
```

mysql> DESCRIBE questions;

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> DESCRIBE answers;

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| answer       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| questions_id | int(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

questions_id is a foreign key that references questions(id)

I found some documentation on [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) but I can't figure out how to use it with an input.

Comment: I see a typo `hasMany()` it's camel case.

Comment: I corrected the hasMany() camel case issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. I am using your code.

```
public function store()
{

    $Question = new Questions;
    $Question->question     = Input::get('question'); 
    $Question->save();


    $Answer = new Answers;
    $Answer->answer       = Input::get('answer');

    // Use the recently created Question id    
    $Answer->questions_id = $Question->id;

    $Answer->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created nerd!');
    return Redirect::action('Controller@index');

}
```

I removed `$Answer->timestamps = false;` because this can be done in your model and your table do not have any `timestamps` column either.

Add `public $timestamps = false;` to your models.

**Questions.php**

```
class Questions extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'questions';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Answers');
    }
}
```

**Answers.php**

```
class Answers extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'answers';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- **To be accurate you should post your database schema.**
- Υou shouldn't use plural for your model names.
- Check the typo I've comment you.
- Why you have the `question` and the `answer` in the same
  form/controller?
- If you have `timestamps` in you db schema, and I mean
  `$table->timestamps()` in your  migrations, you don't have to assign
  them, they are automatically get a value.
- For naming convention use lowercase variable names.

```
$answer = new Answers(['answer' => Input::get('answer')]);
$question = Questions::create(['question' => Input::get('question')]);
$question->answers()->save($answer);
```

Otherwise try the below although the **above should work.**

```
$question = Questions::create(['question' => Input::get('question')]);
$answer   = Answers::create(['answer' => Input::get('answer'),
                             'questions_id' => $question->id]);
```

It's a good idea to define also the inverse relationship for *answers*.

```
public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Questions');
}
```

Comment: This does not work. possibly because i didn't show you my database schema  :(

Comment: @user1082764 I fixed a typo and add an extra solution. Tell me if you get any error?

Comment: I would really appreciate to know the reason of the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

One option I haven't seen presented yet is to use the relationship defined on the model. See the Laravel docs. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

```
$answer = new Answer();
$answer->answer = Input::get('answer');
$question->answers()->save($answer);
```

Comment: I don't think there is something new presented in your answer that is not in the others.